# How to show and hide button for particluar time interval

Tags: iphone

Hi i need to show a button after every 120 second for a time inteval of 20 decond and then the button disppaers and after another 120 sec again the same thigs happen .IF some one can help it would be great .

Regards
Abhi

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `hidden` for hiding buttons. For example.

```
 UIButton *button;
 button.hidden = TRUE; // or FALSE
```

And for the 120 second interval,  you can use `NSTimers`

Check [this link](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSTimer_Class/Reference/NSTimer.html).

Comment: `YES` and `NO` are the conventional `BOOL`s in Cocoa